# Jmeter, Name and value pairs are dynamic in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have situation where name and value pair are dynamic, 
I did two correlations for name and Value separately.
I have used foreach controller and gave input-value as reference name of "Value" regularexpression. which is executing the loop correctly as the match number of Value.
[image][image][image][image]
ForEach controller input index is "Cor_OutputValue" and output index is "Cor_OutputValue1".

Problem is how do i change the "Name" for each request .

Regards,
Sai

Comment: Please share your test plan and problem as a snapshot,if possible, to get a quick response.

Comment: You need to use jmeter 4 and use in index variable the for each controller **name**, if it's named `FEC` Use `${__jm__FEC__idx}`

Answer (score 3):

[ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) save index of loop in a special variable you can use:

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named FEC, then you can access the looping index through ${__jm__FEC__idx}. Index starts at 0

So in case of your controller name is `ForEach Controller` to get corresponding value of `Value` variable use [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function:

```
${__V(Value_${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx})}
```

If your values start with index 1 you can increment different variable,as `idx` inside JSR223 PreProcessor:

```
vars.put("idx", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("__jm__ForEach Controller__idx"))+1));
```

And use it later

```
${__V(Value_${idx})}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But from regular expression we never get index starts at 0. value starts with 1. so how to increment this with "1".

Comment: @user3400540 add to my answer for start with value 1

Comment: I have update screenshots, i tried above logic but still its not working